# Swift 4: What's the equivalent to loading a nib file programmatically, without storyboards?

Tags: swift, storyboard, mapkit

I have some code that I found online that fits my project perfectly. The issue is that I don't use storyboards at all. Instead of using a storyboard file to create the UIView **`(CustomCallOutView)`**, I just create a class with a subclass of UIView. Here's the code that requires a nib file but I don't want to use them. How do I achieve this? The code is below. Thank you!

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
        didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
{
    // 1
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation
    {
       // Don't proceed with custom callout
       return
    }
    // 2
    let starbucksAnnotation = view.annotation as! StarbucksAnnotation
    let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCalloutView", owner: nil, options: nil)
    let calloutView = views?[0] as! CustomCalloutView
    calloutView.starbucksName.text = starbucksAnnotation.name
    calloutView.starbucksAddress.text = starbucksAnnotation.address
    calloutView.starbucksPhone.text = starbucksAnnotation.phone
    calloutView.starbucksImage.image = starbucksAnnotation.image
    let button = UIButton(frame: calloutView.starbucksPhone.frame)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.callPhoneNumber(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    calloutView.addSubview(button)
    // 3
    calloutView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width / 2, y: -calloutView.bounds.size.height*0.52)
    view.addSubview(calloutView)
    mapView.setCenter((view.annotation?.coordinate)!, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that CustomCalloutView doesn't do anything sophisticated:

```
 let calloutView = CustomCalloutView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an *UIView* subclass that is loads a *nib* you can use the following:

```
class YourViewWithNib: UIView {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        loadNib()
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        bounds = frame
        loadNib()
    }

    func loadNib() {
        let nib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(
            "YourNibFileName",
            owner: self,
            options: nil
        )
        let view = nib![0] as! UIView

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(view)

        // if you are using autolayout
        let views = ["nibView": view]
        let hconstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "H:|[nibView]|", 
            metrics: nil, 
            views: views
        )
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(hconstraints)

        let vconstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|[nibView]|", 
            metrics: nil, 
            views: views
        )
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(vconstraints)
    }
}
```

**To add your custom view**, you just can either use `YourViewWithNib(frame: aFrame)` or add a `YourViewWithNib` view in any XIB or Storyboard.